# sim card dont work with adafruit fona

Tags: arduino

Hello i connected my arduino with adafruit fona

1. Vio connects to 5V
2. GND connects to GND
3. Key connects to GND
4. RX connects to digital 2
5. TX connects to digital 3
6. RST connects to digital 4

I connected arduino to pc usb and fona have connected to battery
on the fona  one led is on blue and second blink red.

I use fona.test code and use port monitor to comunicate with fona,

I can read battery charge but,

I cant send sms /read sms 
and i cant do anything with sim card and i dont know what to do. 
On phone this card work.